# How can I limit the width of a button within a TableRow in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button, android-tablelayout

I want to have buttons that take up as little width as necessary. My XML in the Layout file is:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_ok"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:maxWidth="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel" />
</TableRow>
```

I have tried "wrap_content" and "fill_parent" for the layout_width vals, but they don't help. As you can see, I also tried the "maxWidth" property, to no avail. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

So how can I restrict the width of a button to "just enough" to contain its text? I want the "Cancel" button to be approximately the same width as the "OK" button, or as little more as necessary to contain its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I restrict the width of a button to "just enough" to contain its text?

Ideally, remove it (and the OK button) from the table.

The point behind `TableLayout` is to give you characteristics reminiscent of HTML tables, particularly for graybeards like me who overdosed on HTML tables back in the pre-CSS Web development of the 1990's.

In an HTML table, cells expand to fill the width of the widest cell in the column. Same thing here -- the width of the Cancel button is dictated by its column, and I presume that it is in the column dominated by the bars of your bar chart.

From the screenshot, the only thing that should be in the `TableLayout` is the four-row bar chart itself. The "Edit List" label(?), the radio buttons, and the OK/Cancel buttons should be beneath the `TableLayout`. If you want the OK and Cancel buttons to be the same width, use a horizontal `LinearLayout` for them, give them each a width of `0dp`, and give them each a weight of `1`.

Comment: That's not a bar chart, but rather a set of EditText widgets. Nevertheless, I'll try your method.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Do you think users will recognize them as being `EditText` widgets, considering that they do not resemble `EditText` widgets that the users are used to seeing?

Comment: They simply have a different background (the EditTexts, not the users - android:background="#ffcb05"). What our users are used to seeing is like a Duckbilled Platypus with elephantiasis compared to this color uniqueness.

Comment: Actually, I want the buttons as narrow as possible, rather than simply the same width; your method does work, but mine works better for this circumstance (for me, anyway).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Then use `wrap_content` for the width and get rid of the weight within the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I spiffified (or uglified, depending on your POV) the EditTexts because the standard appearance of the EditTexts is bland to say the least, and almost invisible, actually - how would the user even know there was an EditText there? I wouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

I got it - the margin properties can be your friends. I added that to the "Cancel" button, which has been reduced to this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_marginRight="9![enter image description here][1]0dp"
    android:text="@string/button_cancel"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCancel" />
```

...and it looks more to my liking now:

[image]

### UPDATE

Common swear had a good idea:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:paddingLeft="112dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_ok"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is ghastly and will fail quite dramatically as you try other screen sizes.

Comment: This is a one-device app. It will only run on the TC55.

Comment: However, Stack Overflow is not a resource exclusive to you. It is important for other people, who visit this question in the future, to understand the limitations of this approach.

Comment: Good point; I took "you" to mean me, but I guess you meant YOU.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Or less specific. Whatever. :-) While there are a smattering of single-device developers like yourself, the vast majority of Android developers are targeting multiple devices. That inevitably means screens that vary in size and density. Dealing with a bunch of dimension values to handle those variations is a pain and ideally is avoided where possible.

Comment: All you gotta do is throw Bootstrap at it and all your RWD are belong to the Twitterpated, though, right? Or is it Twittersated, better stated?